# Parse don't load content on iPhone 6 Plus

Tags: swift, parse-platform, load

in my app in use Parse and Swift.
The app don't load the content when the app is runned on an iPhone 6 Plus or an iPhone 6 Plus simulator but works good on iPhone 6 and iPhone 6 simulator..
Idk why the content is not loaded ..
Here's what i got in the terminal:

```
    Connecté
2015-05-09 11:08:38.541 MYAPPNAME[39279:1718140] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f919d91c4a0 H:[UIImageView:0x7f919d91bef0(359)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f919d922850 H:[UIImageView:0x7f919d91bef0]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7f919d920da0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f919d9228a0 H:|-(0)-[UIImageView:0x7f919d91bef0]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7f919d920da0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f919d82aa50 UIView:0x7f919d920da0.trailing == UITableViewCellContentView:0x7f919d90ca50.trailingMargin>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f919d829970 UIView:0x7f919d920da0.leading == UITableViewCellContentView:0x7f919d90ca50.leadingMargin>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f919d834d60 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' H:[UITableViewCellContentView:0x7f919d90ca50(412)]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f919d91c4a0 H:[UIImageView:0x7f919d91bef0(359)]>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2015-05-09 11:08:38.544 MYAPPNAME[39279:1718140] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f919d827c60 H:[UIImageView:0x7f919d832410(359)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f919d83f180 H:[UIImageView:0x7f919d832410]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7f919d835ba0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f919d842b60 H:|-(0)-[UIImageView:0x7f919d832410]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7f919d835ba0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f919d835b30 UIView:0x7f919d835ba0.trailing == UITableViewCellContentView:0x7f919d8422d0.trailingMargin>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f919d843bb0 UIView:0x7f919d835ba0.leading == UITableViewCellContentView:0x7f919d8422d0.leadingMargin>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f919d83afa0 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' H:[UITableViewCellContentView:0x7f919d8422d0(412)]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f919d827c60 H:[UIImageView:0x7f919d832410(359)]>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2015-05-09 11:08:38.548 MYAPPNAME[39279:1718140] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f919d82bee0 H:[UIImageView:0x7f919d82e780(359)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f919d83e1b0 H:[UIImageView:0x7f919d82e780]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7f919d839410 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f919d83e200 H:|-(0)-[UIImageView:0x7f919d82e780]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7f919d839410 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f919d810470 UIView:0x7f919d839410.trailing == UITableViewCellContentView:0x7f919d8300d0.trailingMargin>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f919d8104c0 UIView:0x7f919d839410.leading == UITableViewCellContentView:0x7f919d8300d0.leadingMargin>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f919d84cfd0 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' H:[UITableViewCellContentView:0x7f919d8300d0(412)]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f919d82bee0 H:[UIImageView:0x7f919d82e780(359)]>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

I really need your help! :(

Comment: I have similar symptoms at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34323313/parse-queries-not-working-on-iphone-6-plus-after-upgrade-ios-9-2-from-ios-9-1. Did you solve this issue?