# Parse queries not working on iPhone 6 Plus after upgrade to iOS 9.2 from iOS 9.1

Tags: ios, parse-platform, ios9.2

My app uses Parse with local store enabled to save and fetch data. While fetching it queries the local store first and then the network store.

The app worked well for CRUD operations (create, read, update, delete) on all phones.

After updating from iOS 9.1 SDK to 9.2 SDK the app:

- works on all simulators including 6 Plus
- and all phones **except the 6 Plus phone** (6s not tested).

The writes work well, I see them committed to the database (on the cloud). But when I query, I do not get network stored objects created elsewhere, objects created locally show up as they are already in the local store. My debug messages back this up and state that they did not find any network object.

This only happens on the 6 Plus phone.

I found similar symptoms at:
[Parse don't load content on iPhone 6 Plus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30138118/parse-dont-load-content-on-iphone-6-plus)
however I do not have the auto-layout issues shown in that question.